# Bones stuck in default pose even after I change the pose

Tags: animation, bones

[image]I can only move the wrists, feet fingers bones and etc.
Any 'mid' bone such as the elbow I can move but it doesn't change anything on the model.
How can I fix this?

Comment: hello, please share your file (or at least the armature if this is what you want to be checked): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, those bones are not linked to the mesh in any way. Assuming they are in the same armature as the bones that do work:

1. The non-functioning bones do not have matching vertex groups, or have linked vertex groups that are empty, and possibly
2. The non-functioning were not supposed to move anything directly, but they were supposed to move child bones that would affect the mesh, and that parent-child relationship is broken.

If the second is true, it’s pretty easy to fix: parent the correct child to the correct parent bone. If only the first is true, check that the vertex group each bone is supposed to move actually has the same name, and that there is not also a vertex group with the correct name but no weights on its vertices (although you can’t name two groups the same thing, you may find the empty correct name group and think “oh, here it is” when the correct group actually has an incorrect name). One easy way to do this check is to select a vertex that the bone should definitely move, and check what groups it is part of via the 3D view “N” panel.